# Redirect User based on link they've clicked

Tags: php, header

Is there a way to specify the header location based on which link the user has clicked? If possible, I'd prefer doing this in PHP.

I'd like to submit forms when the user clicks on any of a few buttons (i.e. Next, Back, Save, etc.), and they each need to redirect the user differently once the form is submitted.

Example

*HTML - form2.html*

```
<form name="form2" id="form2" method="post" action="form2-exec.php">        
    <!-- Form Elements -->       
    <a href="form1.php"><input type="submit" value="BACK" /></a>
    <a href="form3.php"><input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" /></a>
</form>
```

*PHP - form2-exec.php*

```
// Connect to database
// Insert & ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Statements
header("location: form3.php");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need the anchor tags. Can you try something like:

```
<input type="submit" name="whereto" value="BACK" />
<input type="submit" name="whereto" value="SUBMIT" />
```

PHP - form2-exec.php

```
// Connect to database
// Insert & ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Statements
if ($_GET['whereto'] == 'BACK') {
    header("location: form1.php");
} elseif ($_GET['whereto'] == 'SUBMIT') {
    header("location: form3.php");
}
```

You can find out more about PHP predefined variables at http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php

Comment: Same answer but better explanation.  +1

Comment: It's submitting the form correctly but it isn't redirecting it to either location :-(

Comment: @ficuscr - I was just doing that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use `$_POST['submit']` which will contain the `value` as a value. Use the `name` attribute on your submit buttons as well to make it sure.

Comment: And then just use an if/else statement to redirect them accordingly? I hadn't thought of that :-D

Comment: if($_POST['submit']=='BACK') { /* Go somewhere */ } else { /* Go somewhere else */ }

Comment: Unfortunately that redirects the user to the same page regardless of the button clicked, but using $_POST with @GardnerBickford's solution worked :-D